# How would i configure that a user is only allowed to change it's own account-data?

Tags: permissions, acl, shiro

given Apache Shiro's permission format `domain:action:instance` how would I define that a user may only change it's *own* account-data?

I could do the following but this leads to an enormous explosion of permissions:

`useraccountdata:write:user1` permit to `user1` 
...
`useraccountdata:write:userN` permit to `userN`

What I need instead is something of permission-rules to configure this dynamically.

Something like: `useraccountdata:write:user{n}` permit to `user{n}` automatically for all `n`

Is this supported somehow or am I completely on the wrong path here? If not, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your own version of Authorizer, you could just dynamically add the permission for that user with one of the isPermitted methods.

Comment: so you have some custom code to dynamically add permissions on a user by user basis? I hoped to have a declarative way, oh well, can't have it all I guess.

Comment: Yes. But you might do some customization yourself of the class PermissionAnnotationHandler and AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor. Create your own variant @RequiresPermission that provides a base permission and derives the rest from the context (the method signature, or arguments). This will involve some aspect-oriented programming